# Dynamics: circle diffeo with an irrational rotation number and its rational approximation

Tags: dynamical-systems, arithmetic-dynamics

I need some help in proving the following that arises from the proof of the Denjoy's theorem:

Let $f: [0,1] \to [0,1]$ be an orientation preserving circle diffeomorphism topologically conjugated to the rigid rotation $R_f$ with an irrational rotation number $\rho(f)=[a_1, a_2, ...]$.
Set $\frac{p_n}{q_n}=[a_1,a_2,...,a_n]$, prove that $\nexists \ k$ such that: $|k|\le q_n$ and $f^k(x) \in (x, f^{q_n}(x))$ for any $n$.

$\frac{p_n}{q_n}$ is a rational approximation of the rotation number,
$(x, f^{q_n}(x))$ is the arc of the circle with shortest length and $[a_1,a_2,...,a_n]$ is the continued fraction representation of the number: $$\frac{1}{a_1+\frac{1}{a_2+\frac{1}{\ddots +\frac{1}{a_n}}}}$$

I've been thinking about it for a while but I don't even know where to start, thank you

Comment: You said it: "$(x,f^{q_n}(x))$ is the arc of the circle with shortest length". Assuming that you can use this, what would happen if you could find such a $k$? Otherwise, your claim is what you should show.

Comment: I think that the answer to the question is related to the proof, because maybe you can prove this proposition by contradiction showing that the existence of such $k$ mean that exists a better approximation for the irrational rotation number or something similar.

Comment: As a complement: it is a consequence of the fact that irrational rotations have dense orbits that there are infinitely many integers $q_n$ as you ask, since an orientation-preserving homeomorphism has orbits ordered *exactly* as those of the rotation with the same rotation number. This is all we need for the proof of Denjoy's theorem, that is, *one does not need* to know that the numbers $q_n$ come from the continued fraction.

Comment: I see, thank you. Maybe the formulation of the problem is a bit silly then.. But still I need to prove it for that particular choice of $q_n$

Comment: OK, I have added a proof below.

Answer (score 2):

> **Claim:** There are infinitely many integers $n>0$ such that the intervals $I=(x,f^{-n}(x))$, $f(I), \ldots, f^n(I)$ are pairwise disjoint.

For $k=0,\ldots,n$ we have
$$
f^k(I)=\bigl(f^k(x),f^{k-n}(x)\bigr)
$$
since $f$ is orientation-preserving. Note that the intervals $f^k(I)$ are pairwise disjoint if and only if
$f^k(x) \not \in I$ for $\lvert k \rvert \le n$.
But this property only depends on the ordering of the orbit of $x$, which is the same as the ordering of the orbits of the rotation $R$ with the same rotation number (this simpler property is usually shown earlier). Since $\rho(f)$ is irrational, all negative semiorbits are dense. Hence, there exist infinitely many integers $n>0$ such that $R^k(y)\not\in(y,R^{-n}(y))$ for $|k|\le n$ and $y$. Since orbits are ordered in the same manner, this is equivalent to $f^k(x)\not\in(x,f^{-n}(x))$ for $|k|\le n$ and $x$. We are done.